# Simplifying composition interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, delegation

In the code I am working on I have a structure where some portions of the code depend on the current software session. Software session contains multiple helper objects which are dependency injected by composition.

One example is IRepository injected to it, which contains access to the data repository. And the IRepository contains a DatabaseContext which writes to a database, via IDbContext again which is injected.

SoftwareSession is the only injected common infrastructure for accessing all the way to the database, acting as a gateway. This means when I want to write an object to database, for instance WriteCar I will have to implement 3 interfaces, 2 functions delegating to composed objects and 1 function with implementation. It is clarified in the code fragment below. The WriteCar signatures are defined the same in 3 interfaces (IRepository, ISoftwareSession, IDbContext), 2 places where it is not implemented (Repository, SoftwareSession) which simply calls composited objects related functions and 1 place of actual implementation (IDbContext)

This means when I want to refactor, move code, add functionality or change function signatures I will always have to change 6 places for one function.

I think this provides the best environment for improving testability and it follows best practices where software session wraps access to repository and repository wraps access to data contexts - yet I still am questioning if we can have some better way of writing it once, or do I have a misunderstanding of some concept in the code below?

What is the architecturally more maintainable way of implementing this? Maybe even using some clever way of lambdas or delegates to reduce the amount of code written for each new functionality? Or even some libraries (like automapper simplifies DTOs) or tools to ease generation of this code from some kind of templating mechanism using Visual Studio, Resharper, etc?

Please let me know if I am having some confusion of concepts here. I know some my colleagues have similar views, in which case it may be helpful to clarify misunderstandings of others as well.

```
public class SoftwareSession : ISoftwareSession
{
    ...
    IRepository repository;
    public void WriteCar(Car car){
        repository.WriteCar(car);
    }
    ...
}

public interface ISoftwareSession{
    ...
    void WriteCar(Car car);
    ...
}


public class Repository : IRepository{
    ...
    IDbContext context;
    public void WriteCar(Car car){
        context.WriteCar(car);
    }
    ...        
}

public interface IRepository{
    ...
    void WriteCar(Car car);
    ...
}

public class MyDbContext : IDbContext{
    ...
    public void WriteCar(Car car){
       //The Actual Implementation here.
        ...
    }
    ...
}

public interface IDbContext{
    ...
    void WriteCar(Car car);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Interfaces can inherit too! Why not have a `ICarWriter` interface and then `IRepository : ICarWriter`, `ISoftwareSession : ICarWriter` and so on.

Comment: I believe the problem lies in your Software session implementation, this violates Single responsibility as it appears in your framework that anything going to the database, writeCar, writeCustomer, etc... Must have an acccessor in this class.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane I agree - this is a way of refactoring the interfaces - and makes sense from reducing duplicate code perspective. I am willing to wait for other possible ways of simplifying this though.

Comment: @Dys1 I agree with your view as well, yet isn't this is a pattern that we use when we are using layers (Composition over inheritance)? The database layer is separated from the view model, which uses software session as a separate layer/proxy rather than accessing database context directly. If we decide to change the library we are using for dbcontext e.g. EF to Ado.net with some signature changes we only change it in software session. Yet this is mostly not the case and I am curious if there is a way to implement it as convention over configuration where it is customizable

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, your `IDbContext` and `IRepository` are the same. You would probably like to remove `IDbContext`, or at least to remove methods declared in `IRepository` from it.

Then, both `MyDbContext` and `Repository` would implement `IRepository` and `Repository` class would just be a wrapper around `MyDbContext`.

Then, if `Repository` is only forwarding calls to `MyDbContext`, then you probably don't need that class either.

Furthermore, I don't see that you are doing anything in the `SoftwareSession` apart from forwarding the call to the contained repository. Do you really need `SoftwareSession`, or would it make sense to pass `IRepository` directly to whoever is calling the session object?

Bottom line is that this implementation is swarming with duplication and forwarding. Remove that, and your entire model would become simple.

Comment: Thanks Zoran. IRepository is added because of multiple DbContexts (for instance one context could be DrivingContext where you are looking at road signs, and the other context could be maintenance or administration context where we are implementing the functionalities related to maintenance). In that case repository acts as an aggregator of different contexts in my implementation. If I did not use software session I would have to inject my repository or DbContexts to every other class where these functions are called, wouldn't this cause additional replication and also break encapsulation?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your composition root, I'm not entirely sure how your implementation works, but I'd suggest looking into using an Inversion of Control (IoC) container.  Since your `ISoftwareSession` implementation only depends on an `IRepository` instance, you only need to inject that in the class' constructor.  The same goes for your `IRepository` implementation: you only need to inject your `IDbContext` into the constructor.

With the IoC container, you "register", i.e. wire up your interfaces to your implementation at application startup (in the composition root), and the container takes care of creating the required instances when you resolve the dependencies.  Then all you have to do is get the instance of `SoftwareSession` from the container, and away you go.

So, you could change your `SoftwareSession` implementation like this:

```
public class SoftwareSession : ISoftwareSession
{
    IRepository repository;

    public SoftwareSession(IRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void WriteCar(Car car)
    {
        repository.WriteCar(car);
    }
}
```

And your `Repository` implementation like this:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    IDbContext context;

    public Repository(IDbContext dbContext)
    {
        context = dbContext;
    }

    public void WriteCar(Car car)
    {
        context.WriteCar(car);
    }
}
```

Then here is your composition root:

```
var ioc = new MyIocContainer();

// register your interfaces and their associated implementation types with the IoC container
ioc.Register<ISoftwareSession, SoftwareSession>();
ioc.Register<IRepository, Repository>();
ioc.Register<IDbContext, MyDbContext>();

// resolve the IoC container
ioc.Resolve();

// get your `ISoftwareSession` instance
var session = ioc.GetConcrete<ISoftwareSession>();

var newCar = new Car();

session.WriteCar(newCar);
```

Comment: Rory thanks for your answer. I am already using Ninject with constructor injection for every item in the question. The problem is not the actual injection but the use of  WriteCar interface and implementation delegations in 6 places per function with this architecture. All my remaining mainline classes have only SoftwareSession injected via constructor and they call e.g. WriteCar function on that software session to call. Yet I have to write/duplicate the signature 6 times to get down to the actual implementation.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the use of WriteCar interface and implementation delegations in 6 places per function".  I don't see a `WriteCar` interface.  What is an "implementation delegation"?  and where are the "six places" in a function (method?) that you're talking about?  I don't see that in the code you've provided, so I'm confused...

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying this Rory, I will correct it in the question as well.
The WriteCar signatures are defined the same in 3 interfaces (IRepository, ISoftwareSession, IDbContext), 2 places where it is not implemented (Repository, SoftwareSession) which simply calls composited objects related functions and 1 place of actual implementation (IDbContext)